# Android Null Pointer Exception on Textview setText

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

Android Null pointer exception thrown on settext ran in UI thread forced

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String name=portalData.getFullname();

                        setContentView(R.layout.gradebook);
                            tname.setText(name);

                           }
                });
```

the

i have made a static member of TextView 
on Create Im doing this

super.onStart();

```
    setContentView(R.layout.gradebook);
      tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullname);
```

cannot understand what is causing this 
stacktrace

```
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.example.campus.Gradebook$ObservableDemo$6.run(Gradebook.java:518)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-15 15:19:07.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".vbook" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#007FFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where do you have this `runOnUiThread`. `tname` is null

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reverse these

```
  TextView tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullname); 
  setContentView(R.layout.vbook);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout.

So if your getting NPE even after reversing the above two statements you should check your `vbook.xml` whether you have a textview with id `fullname`.

Also all initializations of your view is generally done in `onCreate` which is the ui thread. I am not sure what you are trying to do.

You have the below in `vbook.xml`

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
```

So change to `TextView tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3)`

Comment: i have tried this setContentView(R.layout.gradebook);
    tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullname);

Comment: Can you copy R.layout.vbook?

Comment: @user2845482 pls post some more relevant code and stack trace

Comment: I have posted the vbook XML

Comment: @user2845482 change to  `TextView tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3)`

Answer (score 3):

The null reference is since the TextView is null.
In order for

```
TextView tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullname);
```

to return the TextView you must initialize the layout first.
Change the code to and you'll do fine:

```
setContentView(R.layout.vbook);    
TextView tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullname);
```

Comment: I have posted complete details and stacktrace kindly check

Answer (score 1):

**setContentView(layout)** should always be called before you map your views using **findViewById(id)**

If same error occurs after reversing it make sure the id you are trying to map is available in your layout file

Comment: i have changed the order but still same nullpointer exception

Comment: make sure the textview is available in your layout file with id fullname and post your stack trace

Comment: I have posted complete details andstacktrace

Comment: as i said in my answer the id you are trying to map should exist in the layout file you are using in setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

As @Ravi said Set contentview should always come before binding view.
In addition to that, there is no id like R.id.fullname in your xml posted. Instead there is textview3
So, try this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.gradebook);// I assume gradebook is your xml file 

tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);  //textView3 is the id you passed in TextView.
```

Hope this helps you.